# Enzyme simulate('change') on select does not increase func coverage

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, code-coverage, enzyme, jestjs

I've got a component with a select inside it

```
<select onChange={this.handleChange}>
    {this.props.options.map(this.renderOption)}
</select>
```

and the following function

```
handleChange(e) {
    const element = e.target;
    this.props.onChange.call(null, e, {
        value: element.value,
        label: element.options[element.selectedIndex].textContent,
    });
}
```

I'm wrote a test in **Jest** and **Enzyme**, like this:

```
const onChange = jest.fn();
// ....
component.find('select').simulate('change');
expect(onChange).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

The problem is that my **% Funcs** coverage is at **83.33%** for this test because it thinks that the `handleChange` function is not being called. All the other coverages (% Stmts, % Branch, % Lines) are at 100%, except for this one. Is this an enzyme/jest bug, or am I doing something wrong?

PS: I tried writing a dummy test where I would call `handleChange` manually and the coverage goes to 100%. So, it's definitely something to do with that.

**Edit, to clarify:** The `handleChange` function is being called, the test works. The problem is that the coverage doesn't count that the function is being called.

Comment: Try adding `sinon` to your test file and spy on the component. `sinon.spy(component.prototype, 'handleChange');` Add this right before you create your component wrapper with `shallow()`

Comment: @KyleRichardson How would that help? Is sinon going to mark the function as covered, or what?

Comment: Check this out: http://sinonjs.org/. What you're trying to do is what `sinon` is designed for.

Comment: @KyleRichardson But, the function is being called, the test works. The problem is that the coverage doesn't count that the function is being called.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood. Not exactly sure how to help in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what the case was for me.

```
SelectComponent.defaultProps = {
    options: [],
    onChange: () => {},
};
```

It was because of the default property function. When I unit tested, I replaced it with a mock function, so that function was never called, thus making the coverage not count it.

Comment: For me it was crucial that I actually called the default function in the test. So it wasn't enough to just check that `onChange` was not null, I had to call `onChange()`.